# Can't make sense of this PCL code: calling a member method on a raw pointer without ->

Tags: c++, clang, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to build PCL with Clang 14 and it fails on `SparseMatrix` class with an error `member reference base type 'MatrixEntry<T> *' is not a structure or union`, when trying to compile the following code: `for (int ii=0; ii<m_ppElements[i].size(); ii++)`, where m_ppElements is declared as `MatrixEntry<T>** m_ppElements;`

So the error is correct, a C-style array pointer has no member `size()` or in fact any methods whatsoever which could be accessed without operator `->` and `.` is not overloadable, neither are there any casts.

However this code builds just fine with MSVC 17 and Clang 11.

The code in question: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/surface/include/pcl/surface/3rdparty/poisson4/sparse_matrix.hpp

Comment: The code seems incorrect. Is the code used by the library (given that it is third party code)? While unused template functions shouldn't be compiled, some compilers might check them for some errors anyway.